# How to get/reuse cudnnHandle (cudnnHandle_t) in custom Tensorflow op

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cudnn

I've created my own Tensorflow op to be used on GPU modeled after what the [Tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op#implement_the_kernel_for_the_op) says to do, and I have the following files below (abbreviated for clarity). My op needs to be run repeatedly in a model training loop, and creating/destroying the `cudnnHandle_t` context object is causing a lot of overhead and really slowing things down according to the GPU profiler.

I've spent a few hours poking around the Tensorflow API to see how some of the CuDNN-accelerated operations are implemented but cannot really figure out how I should properly use CuDNN within the Tensorflow framework for creating custom ops.

My question is, how can I avoid creating and destroying a new `cudnnHandle_t` object every time my op is executed? I'm currently working with Tensorflow version `2.3.1` but don't mind solutions from newer versions.

```
# # # custom_tensorflow_cudnn_op.cc

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"


using namespace tensorflow;

REGISTER_OP("CustomTensorflowCudnnOp")
    .Input("x: float32")
    .Output("y: float32")
    .SetShapeFn([](::tensorflow::shape_inference::InferenceContext* c) {
      c->set_output(0, c->input(0));
      return Status::OK();
    });

void custom_tensorflow_cudnn_op_func(const float* x, float* y);

class CustomTensorflowCudnnOp : public OpKernel {
    public:
        explicit CustomTensorflowCudnnOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {}

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            // Get the input tensor
            const Tensor& x = context->input(0);

            // Create output tensor
            Tensor* y = NULL;
            OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(0, x.shape(), &y));

            // Run op function
            custom_tensorflow_cudnn_op_func(x.flat<float>().data(), y->flat<float>().data());
        }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("CustomTensorflowCudnnOp").Device(DEVICE_GPU), CustomTensorflowCudnnOp);
```

```
# # # custom_tensorflow_cudnn_op.cu

#include <cudnn.h>


void custom_tensorflow_cudnn_op_func(const float* x, float* y){
    cudnnHandle_t cudnn;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreate(&cudnn));

    /*
    ...
    do work using cudnn functions/objects and custom CUDA __global__ functions
    ...
    */

    cudnnDestroy(cudnn);
}
```